# How do I combine coal into a gift?

Tags: steam

I'm approaching my 7th coal in Steam's Winter Sale.  When selecting my coal in my inventory, it says I can combine 7 coal into a prize from the Great Gift Pile.  I see nowhere to actually combine the coal, though.

Is there a button in the inventory screen that appears whenever 7 or more coal are in the inventory, or is the combining done on a separate screen entirely?

Comment: I'm also curious about whether crafting means you get to choose your prize.

Comment: @Dave when you do it, could you tell me what you got? I'm curious whether it was worth it.

Comment: @ver I got a 50% off coupon for Max Payne 2 :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you open up your inventory and select your coal, there is a button that is displayed in the bottom right of the window that lets you "craft" them into a prize. This button only shows up when you have at least 7 pieces of coal in your inventory.

To be clear about the process, you do not get to choose your prize when combining coal - you are randomly given a coupon or a game.